# How to add this functionality on field limiter

Tags: magento2

Also should have the display number of products on a page be: **(20, 50, 100, all)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to enable this setting in your store configuration here

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Allow All Products per Page : **Yes**

[image]

Hope this will help you!